# Deleting file from Aws-S3 bucket issue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to delete a file from Aws-S3 bucket after loading data using a procedure from postgresql.
But deleting the file is happening before loading the data . Can anybody suggest why this is
happening?

```
const Client = require('pg').Client;

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
// Connect to Postgresql
exports.handler = (body, context, callback) => {
const client = new Client({
host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
port: process.env.RDS_PORT,
database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE
});

return client.connect()
.then(() => {
const sql = `call public.p_library_ld()`;
return client.query(sql)
.then((v) => {    const { rows } = v;
                  callback(null,rows);
             })
.catch((err) => callback(err, null))
.then(()=> client.end());
})
.catch(err => console.error('connection error', err.stack))
};


const s3 = new aws.S3(); // Pass in opts to S3 if necessary


s3.deleteObject({
Bucket: 'XXX-dev',
Key: 'XXX-dev/AWS_library.csv'
                }, 
function(err, data) {
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
else     console.log(data);
                     });
```

Comment: Welcome! maybe [this chapter from eloquent JS](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this code can execute as is.
The code that deletes the file from s3 is outside the lambda function.

Besides this, I think the reason the s3 delete executes first is that the code runs asynchronously.

The first part that connects to postgres and executes something returns a promise, and also the s3 deletion also returns a promise.

That means these 2 pieces of code return at once, and run in parallel.

Moving the s3 deletion part inside the deepest callback should resolve the issue

```
    const Client = require('pg').Client;
    
    const aws = require('aws-sdk');
    // Connect to Postgresql
    exports.handler = (body, context, callback) => {
        const client = new Client({
            host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
            user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
            port: process.env.RDS_PORT,
            database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE
        });
    
        return client.connect()
            .then(() => {
                const sql = `call public.p_library_ld()`;
                return client.query(sql)
                    .then((v) => {
                        const { rows } = v;
                        callback(null, rows);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => callback(err, null))
                    .then(() => {
                        client.end();
                        //Delete object from S3
                        const s3 = new aws.S3(); // Pass in opts to S3 if necessary
    

                        s3.deleteObject({
                            Bucket: 'XXX-dev',
                            Key: 'XXX-dev/AWS_library.csv'
                        },
                            function (err, data) {
                                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                                else console.log(data);
                            });
                    });
            })
            .catch(err => console.error('connection error', err.stack))
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Spiff looks correct. Before the Postgres command completes execution, the s3 delete Object call gets processed, so that answer should solve your problem. Just suggesting an easier code syntax here. With NodeJS 8+ runtimes on AWS Lambda, an easier async-await syntax is also possible, which makes the code more readable.

```
exports.handler = async (body, context, callback) => {
    // ** Note the async keyword here **
    const client = new Client({
        host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
        user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
        port: process.env.RDS_PORT,
        database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE
    });
    try {
        const conn = await client.connect();
        const sql = `call public.p_library_ld()`;
        const v = await client.query(sql);
        const { rows } = v;
        const s3 = new aws.S3();

        await s3
            .deleteObject({
                Bucket: 'XXX-dev',
                Key: 'XXX-dev/AWS_library.csv'
            })
            .promise();
        return rows;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('error while processing', err);
    }
};
```